# Who designed the Mandalorian armor?

Tags: star-wars, boba-fett

Who designed the Mandalorian armor for Boba Fett within the Star Wars Universe? (more so than who created the design and artistic look for the films although any information/links would be welcomed.)

Did he, himself make his own armor?( and if so is it a variation of a existing suit? )

Comment: Boba's armor looks a lot like Jango's, not to mention many other Mandalorian warriors seen in The Clone Wars TV series. Even the first-gen Clone armor is reminiscent of Mandalorian armor design. The armor seems fairly widespread among Mandalorians, but *who designed* it is a really intriguing question. I think it's likely that it doesn't *have* a single designer, but was an armor that was iterated upon through the generations of Mandalore warring with its Galactic neighbors.

Comment: In or out of universe?

Comment: Primarily in universe.

Comment: If it is called Mandalorian, I would think that the Mandalorians designed it.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mandalorian_armor gives a history about the armor and specifics about variation in Jango and Boba's armor.

Comment: I think I can build one now,lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mandalorian_armor#cite_note-The_Mandalore_Plot-0) says this:

> The ancient Mandalorian crusaders wore helmets over cloaks. By the Mandalorian Civil War, two styles of armor had emerged—the formidable traditional armor of the warrior clans like Death Watch, and those of the pacifist New Mandalorians. Death Watch's female warriors, the Nite Owls, wore a different set of armor.
>
> Jango Fett wore Mandalorian armor, though Prime Minister Almec expressed bewilderment as to how since Fett was a bounty hunter rather than a Mandalorian. The Kaminoans who cloned him to create the Grand Army of the Republic took inspiration from his suit for the clone trooper armor.
> After Fett was killed by Jedi Master Mace Windu during the Battle of Geonosis, his helmet was used by Boba as a bomb in an attempt on Windu's life. By the Age of the Empire, Boba had acquired his own Mandalorian armor.

The Starwars.com Databank says this about [Boba Fett](http://www.starwars.com/databank/boba-fett)

> He wore Mandalorian armor reminiscent of his father’s, beat up from his many jobs, and piloted the fearsome Slave I starship.

In comparing Jango and Boba's armors side by side.

[image]

You see that Jango (on the right) looks a lot more professional and "production" in appearance, as if he purchased his. **Boba's, on the other hand, looks incomplete and as if he has scrapped pieces of armor or plating together himself.**

Comment: Awesome. Appreciate it.